# Firebase failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a sign in project . when i try to sign in it tells me that
  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long. i don't know why i cheeked the codes and everything its seems to be okay for me

this is my main class

```
package com.example.median1.demo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtphone,edtPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        edtPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        edtphone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);


        FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference table_user=database.getReference("user");

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                final ProgressDialog mdialog=new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mdialog.setMessage("please wait....");
                mdialog.show();

                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                          //check if user dose not exist
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(edtphone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                            //get user information

                            mdialog.dismiss();


                            user user1 = dataSnapshot.child(edtphone.getText().toString()).getValue(user.class);


                            if (user1.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {


                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "sign in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "sign in is failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "user dose not exist in Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and this is the class where i get the string from the firebase

```
package com.example.median1.demo;

/**
 * Created by median1 on 10/31/2017.
 */

public class user {
   private String Name;
   private String Password;

    public user() {
    }

    public user(String name, String password) {
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did the logs tell which line might be causing this?

Comment: Please share your database structure.

Comment: yeah sure but i just want to say that in the password failed if there was only  text it will not be a problem but if there was a number the application will get this error

Comment: Password: 234 is not a String, should be Password: "234"

Comment: okay lets make the password lal234 it will give me the same error

Comment: yes because it does not have " "

Comment: still giving me the same error  ;(

Comment: no wait peter hadded u were right i just forgot to run the application again with the previews changes because i was making some changes so thank you very much for the help

Comment: no problem, anytime!

Answer (score 0):

> In firebase data one child have String type password ("ala") and one has Long (234).
>   Please make string.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically typecast to string ?